# Updating VS Code user settings via an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a simple extension for toggling the visibility of test files in VS Code. Here's my current approach:

```javascript
const testGlobs = [
  '**/__tests__',
  '**/__mocks__',
  '**/*.spec.js',
]

function hideTests() {
  const exclude = workspace.getConfiguration('files.exclude', vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global)
  testGlobs.forEach(glob => exclude.update(glob, true, vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global));
  console.log(exclude) // does not reflect the updated values
}
```

This appears to have no impact. The settings for the file patterns remain `false` in my user settings file, as they do when logging out the values of `exclude` at the end of the code snippet.

How do I correctly update settings via extension code?

Comment: I think the `exclude` object is not updated automatically. To check whether the changes where applied consider to call `workspace.getConfiguration()` instead after you updated your settings. Maybe you also need to invoke that command in the callback of the `update` method.

Comment: Yeah, that occurred to me. But I'm checking the user settings file itself and there are no changes there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it. The code I posted was actually throwing an error, but the `update` method is asynchronous and therefore the error was getting swallowed. By using async/await on the function, I was able to see the error, which was something like:

`'files.exclude.**/__tests__' is not a registered configuration.`

Basically, I had to update the `exclude` configuration in its entirety, not an individual key under it because those keys are just part of the configuration value -- they aren't actual configuration keys themselves. The working solution:

```javascript
async function hideTests() {
  const files = workspace.getConfiguration('files', ConfigurationTarget.Global)
  const exclude = files.get('exclude')
  testGlobs.forEach(g => exclude[g] = true)
  await files.update('exclude', exclude, ConfigurationTarget.Global)
}
```