# Update user/workspace settings from vs code extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to update setting.json from my vs code extension and I want to add below code

```
 "files.associations": {
        "*.app": "auraComponent"
    }
```

In other words I want to add below key value pair from extension to the users who are going to install my app

[image]

So I tried putting the below code in extension.js but it didn't update the settings.

```
import { ConfigurationTarget, workspace } from 'vscode';

const configuration = workspace.getConfiguration('files.associations');
configuration.update('.app', 'auraComponent', ConfigurationTarget.Global).then(() => {
    // take action here
});
```

Could someone please suggest if I am using the right approach to update the user or workspace settings and also if the code inside extension.js would be executed automatically or not.

**Update**

I have added extension.js and included the js code as mentioned by mark in his answer

and update my package.json as below

```
"main": "./extension",
"activationEvents": [
    "*"
],
```

If I run my extension on debug mode then it works fine but not working in real time.

Comment: It didn't work sir

Comment: Could you please confirm if extension.js would be auto executed on user's vs code?

Comment: I meant, I want to updated files.associations in user's vs code settings but it didn't update user's settings.json

Comment: Updated my question with the screenshot

Comment: Oh, I get it - sorry for my confusion

Comment: no worries, could you please help on how it can be achieved?

Comment: Did you set breakpoints to see if your code is ever executed?

Comment: what if `files.associations` is not in `settings.json`

Comment: I think it is but if it is not could you help how to add key-value pair under file.associates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works whether there is a pre-existing `files.association` setting or not.  If there is already one, the new association is added to it (and so may be located somewhere other than the end of the settings file - otherwise a wholly new `files.associations` setting will be added to the very end of the `settings.json` file..

```js
const fileConfiguration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('files');
const associations = fileConfiguration.get('associations');

associations['*.app'] = "auraComponent";

fileConfiguration.update('associations', associations, vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global).then(() => {

    // take action here
});
```

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566662/836330.

As explained there, what you really want to update is the `associations` object, that is the value to be updated.  `"*.app": "auraComponent` is not a configuration key.  `files.associations` is the key and there is an object `{...}` which is its value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my extension.js with your code, this doesn't add it in the associations could you please confirm if I need to do something to execute this code also?

Comment: I tested it several times.  Because of the asynchronous nature of the update it won't actually update for some time.  Put a breakpoint on a `console.log("asdasd")` in the `then` portion, it should be hit and only then will the setting have been updated.  As I mentioned if you already have a `files.associations` somewhere in the file, that will be updated, so check there too.

Comment: And is your extension activated?  Use an activation event of `"onStartupFinished"` for testing.

Comment: I am new to VS code extension development, I am not sure where to see console.log in vs code and I have your code in extension.js and I don't know when extension.js would be executed

Comment: I have pasted my extension folder in .vscode/extensions folder and I can see my extension under the installed extension on my windows machine now I update my extension reload the vs code and then expect my association to update it.

Comment: Debug your extension first.  It will open a window for testing, you can choose some pre-existing folder and see the change in that folder's settins.json (and probably in your original extension code's  settings.json too). But you need to learn about `activationEvents` too - your extension may not even be running.

Comment: I ran my application on debug mode, everything is working as expected now, now if I publish my app, still nothing is working

Comment: I have updated my question, I have added main and activationEvents but still no luck